# How to return values in column from StarBasic to Calc

Tags: scripting, return-value, libreoffice

I am trying to move some custom functions from GoogleSheets to LibreOffice Calc.

In GoogleSheets I can return a sequence of values as `[1,2,3]` to have them on the same row, and as `[[1,2,3]]` to have them on the same column.

In Libreoffice till now I have been able to return ony a few values in the same row, using the code stub below and pressing Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Enter instead of Enter. But, I can't find the way to get return values to be palced in the same column.

```
Function mya() as Variant 
    mya = Array(3,2,1)
End Function
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all values in a single column, use the following function with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
Function mya() as Variant 
    Dim myarray(2, 0) As Integer
    myarray(0, 0) = 1
    myarray(1, 0) = 2
    myarray(2, 0) = 3
    mya = myarray
End Function
```

Documentation is under "Multi-Dimensional Data Fields" at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Arrays.

Comment: Your sample is working, I will build upon it, thank you. Anyhow, I stress (for people who may need it) that with Calc running in FreeBSD, wich runs in a VMWare virtual machine in OSX, the keyboard sequence must be, Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Enter.